# Angular Batarang conflicting with ocLazyLoad

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oclazyload, batarang

I was making a POC to test ocLazyLoad for lazy loading the parts of app.
After lot of debugging, I found out that Angular Batarang is conflicting with ocLazyLoad in some way.

I'm getting following error in reject callback of promise when I lazy load a controller.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at module.exports (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:1060:20)
    at chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:1066:7
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at module.exports (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:1064:21)
    at chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:1360:5
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost/js/library/angular.js:4718:19)
    at callInvoke (http://localhost/js/library/ocLazyLoad.js:317:55)
    at _invokeQueue (http://localhost/js/library/ocLazyLoad.js:322:29)
    at _register (http://localhost/js/library/ocLazyLoad.js:206:21)
    at success (http://localhost/js/library/ocLazyLoad.js:647:37)
```

routing config:

```
 $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: "/",
            templateUrl: 'js/modules/p1/p1.html',
            controller: 'p1Controller as vm',
            resolve: {
                loadMyCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    var a = $ocLazyLoad.load('js/modules/p1/p1.js');
                    a.then(function success(args) {
                        console.log('success');
                        return args;
                    }, function error(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        return err;
                    });
                    return a;
                }]
            }
        });
```

**My lazyloading works perfectly when I disable the batarang extension.**

Looking forward to some help from either of the teams (ocLazyLoad or batarang)

Comment: Just disable batarang, this extension is totally useless.
All you need is this snippet in chrome: `angular.element($0).scope()` and you get a better picture of how angular works.

Comment: I know that command but it is easier to look at scope hierarchy using batarang

Comment: what angular version do you use ? I used to use both successfuly

Comment: @DMCISSOKHO  I'm using v1.5.8